# Why define the Lebesgue-Integral just for measurable functions?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Usually, the Lebesgue integral, for example on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration), is defined for non-negative measureable functions as
$$
 \int_E f \, d\mu := \sup\left\{ \int_E s \, d\mu : 0 \le s \le f, s \text{ simple } \right\}.
$$
But why suppose that $f$ should be measureable? This is not used in the definition here, so we could define this supremum for arbitrary functions $f : X \to [0,\infty)$?

Comment: Because then you wouldn't have $\int(f+g) = \int f + \int g$.

Comment: Do you have an example where this fails for non-measurable functions?

Comment: Take a non-measurable set $A \subset [0,1]$, let $B = [0,1]\setminus A$, and $f = \chi_A,\; g = \chi_B$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: That is really not a good reasoning since this fails in general also for measurable functions if the expressions appearing on the RHS of TonyK's identity are not integrable (let $\Omega=[0,1]$ and take $f(x)\equiv\frac{1}{x^2}$ and $g(x)\equiv -\frac{1}{x^2}$). The problem is rather that for nonmeasurable numerical functions there is no sequence of simple functions converging pointwise and being L1-cauchy... btw this comment is also dedicated to 'TonyK' if he considers the same reasoning...

Comment: @Freeze_S The question considers specifically non-negative functions. One can define "the integral" of any non-negative function $f$ as the $\sup$ of the integrals of non-negative simple functions $\leqslant f$, and then you have the additivity of the integral for all non-negative measurable functions, with finite integral or not, but for non-measurable functions, the additivity generally doesn't hold.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Ah ok yes then that's true...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Lebegue's original approach needs them to be measurable in order to be well defined. Then one can show that Lebegue's approach and the one mentioned here are equivalent.

Comment: What is Lebesgue's original approach?

Comment: Devide the codomain into $B_{k;n}:=(\frac{k-1}{n},\frac{k}{n}]$ for $k=1,\ldots,n^2$ and sum them up as $\sum_{k=1}^{n^2}\frac{k}{n}\mu(f^{-1}(B_{k;n}))$. Then let $n\to\infty$.

Comment: And there you need that taking the preimage of half opens is measurable

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, that if the integral is finite then the function has to be measurable; see: Royden Fitzpatrick "Real Analysis, 4th edition" chapter 5.3. Their proof works for unbounded functions over infinite-measure spaces too.